# Do I need to install linux on my laptop to write with Netwide Assembler(NASM) and run it?

Tags: linux, installation, nasm

I plan to learn assembly language. My laptop is 64 bit with windows 10. Do I need to install linux on my laptop to write programs with NASM and run it?

Comment: NASM runs on Windows

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-NASM-for-Windows-10-64-bit